# How to get the url of a template literals and build another page with it?

Tags: javascript

still learning javascript step-by-step.
I have trouble understanding how to get the url created in a template literal and use it to build another page with it.
I need to build a two pages app with vanilla javascript. The first page, the index, contains portrait of artists and, when you click on a portrait, you go to the second page with more infos about the artist.

The first page is built with a json file.
I use modules, so for now I have 4 modules.

```
export async function fetchData() {
    try{
        const response = await fetch("modules/data.json");
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
    catch (err){
        console.log(err);
        return [];
    }   
};

export class Artists {
 constructor(name, id, portrait) {
     this.name = name;
     this.id = id;
     this.portrait = portrait;
 };

 displayIndex(){
     return `<div class="artists-id">
     <a class="frame-link" href="artists.html?id=${this.id}">
       <img class="photo" src="Photos/Artists ID Photos/${this.portrait}" alt="${this.name}"></img>
       <h2 class="name">${this.name}</h2>
     </a>`;
 };

 displayBanner(){
  return `<span class="photo-info">
  <h2 class="name2">${this.name}</h2>
<span class="photo-id">
  <img class="photo-mini" src="Photos/Artists ID Photos/${this.portrait}/${this.portrait}" alt="${this.name}></img>
</span>`;
}
};

import {fetchData} from "/modules/dataService.mjs"
import {Photographers} from "/modules/photographer.mjs"

class Index {
    constructor() {
        this.artists = [];
        this.displayedArtists = [];
    }
    async getArtists() {
        const data = await fetchData();
        let resdata =  data.artists
        resdata.forEach(artist => {
            this.artists.push(
                new Artists(
                    artist.name,
                    artist.id,
                    artist.portrait
                )
            );
        })
        this.displayedArtists = this.Artists;
    }
    listArtists() {
        let output = '';
        this.displayedArtists.forEach((artist) => {
            output += artist.displayIndex();
        })
        document.getElementById("artists").innerHTML = output;
    }
    async run () {
        await this.getArtists();
        this.listArtists();
    }
}

let Index = new Index();
Index.run()
```

The fourth module “artistPage” is empty for now.
I want to use it to grab the url of a clicked artist, and create the second page using the displayBanner function inside an html element of the second page.

Comment: You mean when you are at `artists.html?id=1` you want to call `displayBanner` with `1` (the artist id). So are you asking how to get the artist id from the url (`1` in this case)?

Comment: These aren't really runnable snippets.  They could just be code-formatted.

Comment: @MoshFeu yes it's exactly that.

Comment: [`URLSearchParams.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get#examples) to rescue

Comment: I'd suggest next time to ask the shortest version of question you can. Then can search this question in Google and you'll get an answer (this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/863110)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a custom url based on some parameter you just need to add a route with :[id name] and then you can href it for when you need to change the page.

Example:

```
<Route path="/Homepage/:user" element = {<HomePage/>}/>

window.location.href=`/Homepage/?name=${user}`
```

In the first line I add that line to my router file so you can just store that wherever your handling routing. Then the second line is where I actually call the route and I use template literals in order to generate a custom name based on my parameter which in this case is a username but you can use whatever.

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals